# d3 TypeScript key function recommended approach?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I'm trying to wrap my head around the best approach to writing key functions for d3 in TypeScript.

I have data with the signature `{key: number, value: number}`, and I want to write a key function that returns `d.key` that can be passed to the `.data()` function.

As it stands now, the following works:

```
dataset = {key: number, value: number}[];
key = (d: any) => d.key;

d3.selectAll('rect')
  .data(this.dataset, this.key)
```

However, whenever I try to define the key function as follows:

```
key = (d: {key: number, value: number}) => d.key;
```

I get the following error based on the overloads for `.data()`:

```
Overload 1 of 3, '(data: { key: number; value: number; }[], key?: ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window, unknown, string>): Selection<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(d: { key: number; value: number; }) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window, unknown, string>'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(data: ValueFn<SVGSVGElement, unknown, unknown[]>, key?: ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window, unknown, string>): Selection<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ key: number; value: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGSVGElement, unknown, unknown[]>'.
      Type '{ key: number; value: number; }[]' provides no match for the signature '(this: SVGSVGElement, datum: unknown, index: number, groups: SVGSVGElement[] | ArrayLike<SVGSVGElement>): unknown[]'.
```

What is the recommended way of specifying a type-safe key function when working with d3 in TypeScript?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am stuck with the same issue. :(

Comment: @Himanshu I ended up having to keep the key argument signature as any

Comment: Found a better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61045443/3662102 :)