# How to make data() key function to work with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I am trying to use a custom key function for `.data()` with `.selectAll()` selection in D3. But, making it TypeScript compatible is becoming such a pain.

The elements are not getting removed properly without the key function as D3 uses the index to check for updates by default.

So, here is the **JavaScript** code snippet, working all fine as expected:

```js
const circles = svg
        .select("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(data, d => d.val);
```

Trying the same with **TypeScript**,

```js
interface IData {
  val: number;
}
```

**Attempt 1**

```js
const circles = svg
        .select("g")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data<IData>(data, (d) => d.val);
```

```
Object d is of type 'unknown'.  TS2571

    35 |         .select("g")
    36 |         .selectAll("circle")
  > 37 |         .data<IData>(data, (d) => d.val);
```

**Attempt 2**

```js
const circles = svg
        .select("g")
        .selectAll<SVGSVGElement, IData>("circle")
        .data<IData>(data, (d) => d.val);
```

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(data: IData[], key?: ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | null, IData, string> | undefined): Selection<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(this: SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | null, d: IData) => number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | null, IData, string>'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(data: ValueFn<BaseType, unknown, IData[]>, key?: ValueFn<SVGSVGElement | Element | EnterElement | Document | Window | null, IData, string> | undefined): Selection<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'IData[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<BaseType, unknown, IData[]>'.
      Type 'IData[]' provides no match for the signature '(this: BaseType, datum: unknown, index: number, groups: BaseType[] | ArrayLike<BaseType>): IData[]'.  TS2769
```

And, it is all working fine without the key function for data:

```js
const circles = svg
        .select("g")
        .selectAll<SVGSVGElement, IData>("circle")
        .data<IData>(data);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As can be seen from the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_data) the key function needs to return a string (emphasis mine):

> A *key* function may be specified to control which datum is assigned to which element, replacing the default join-by-index, **by computing a string identifier** for each datum and element.

This can also be seen by looking at the [type definitions](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L750) for `selection.data()`:

```
data<NewDatum>(data: NewDatum[], key?: ValueFn<GElement | PElement, Datum | NewDatum, string>): Selection<GElement, NewDatum, PElement, PDatum>;
```

Herein, the key function is defined as

```
key?: ValueFn<GElement | PElement, Datum | NewDatum, string>
```

with the [`ValueFn`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L81) type being

```
export type ValueFn<T extends BaseType, Datum, Result> = (this: T, datum: Datum, index: number, groups: T[] | ArrayLike<T>) => Result;
```

Looking at the above two definitions it is easy to see that the `Result` type parameter is set to string for the key function definition, which is the reason for your compiler error.

Returning a string from your key function will solve this issue:

```
.data(data, d => "" + d.val);
```

Comment: I tried converting result to string, but I now get a error on the 'd' in 'd.val' saying 'Object is of type unkown'. this is strange because typescript knows what my data is, when i hover data it shows `const data: PieArcDatum<PieSliceType>[]`. So why is 'd' of type unknown?

Comment: @NicoWheat Hard to tell without seeing more of your code. I suggest you set up a demo and post a question of your own.

Comment: I have the same problem. It’s not clear how to cast the parameter correctly without the compiler thinking you have transformed your data type.

Comment: @Kraken Your data type is not transformed at all. Why should the compiler interpret it like that? It’s just about the key function returning a string value.  Please clarify your problem.

Comment: I didn't say the data changed types. I said the compiler thought it changed. Thanks, but I already figured out my issue

Answer (score 1):

After I stumbled into this mystifying error message;

> Object is of type 'unknown' 
> `` .data(nodes, d => `${d.id}`) `` 
>                      `~`

*I thought I could get away without specifying the type*

You might need to satisfy the types of the `selectAll` first. Note the `INode` type

```js
import { select } from "d3-selection";

interface INode { id: number }
let nodes: INode[] = [
    { id: 0 },
    { id: 1 },
]

select('#d3') // <div id="d3"></div>
    .selectAll<SVGSVGElement, INode>('.node') // <template class="node"></template>
    .data<INode>(nodes, d => d.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m using react + typescript generics. I finally figured this out, I think. I kept running into problems where using the old js pattern of `data(d => d.val)` confused the compiler as to what data type would pass afterward. Then I discovered the key function and struggled a bit with that as well. Finally, it seems to be happy, and the data type is consistent later on in the chain. Bear in mind, passing the generic key as props to my component helped, because I don’t need to get it from the `d` value.

```js
…
.data(data, () => xKey as string)
```

I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You should try it like that:

```js
d3.selectAll<SVGCircleElement, IDataItem>, before calling .data(), where is IData = IDataItem[]
```