# D3.js & Typescript generics - selection.data() & K extends keyof T

Tags: typescript, d3.js, typescript-generics

**Update**
Here is a [link](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#joining-data) to D3’s `selection.data` API, and a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-d3-heatmap-rv82sb?file=/src/index.tsx) for you hands on types.

**The goal** is to have a generically typed interface, and pass a property key (also generic) to reference the given key on the given type during implementation.

I can’t seem to get the typing right.

**The code**

I have an interface with two properties:

```js
interface Props<T, K extends keyof T> {
  data: T[]
  dataKey: K
}
```

I try to use this in my function:

```js
const Heatmap = <T, K extends keyof T>({ data, dataKey }: Props<T, K>) => {
  …
  const svg = d3.select.<some other chained fns>

  // then later
  svg
   .append(‘g’)
   .selectAll(‘rect’)
   .data<T>(d => d[dataKey]) // problem code
}
```

Compiler complains under the data callback:

```js
Argument of type '(this: SVGGElement, d: T) => T[K]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T[] | Iterable<T> | ValueFn<SVGGElement, T, T[] | Iterable<T>>'.
  Type '(this: SVGGElement, d: T) => T[K]' is not assignable to type 'ValueFn<SVGGElement, T, T[] | Iterable<T>>'.
    Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'T[] | Iterable<T>'.
      Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'T[] | Iterable<T>'.
        Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'T[] | Iterable<T>'.
          Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'T[] | Iterable<T>'.
            Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
              Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
                Type 'T[K]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
                  Type 'T[keyof T]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
                    Type 'T[string] | T[number] | T[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
                      Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.ts(2345)
```

In vanilla js, the data callback looks like:

```js
data(d => d.<key>)
```

I have looked all over and could not manage to piece it together. I fiddled with mapped types, indexed types, using the Record utility, but I cannot make it work. I also experimented with the optional key parameter callback. Nothing seems to appease `tsc`. What am I missing here? Why doesn’t this work as I wrote it?

FWIW, the typescript code I have here does work in the browser, but `tsc` won't compile

TIA

Comment: what is the type of `d`?

Comment: @TobiasS. The type of `d` is `T`.  Both property keys are strings, one value is a Date, the other is a number. If both indexes are strings, the actual value type shouldn’t matter here, right?

Comment: what is the type of `svg`?

Comment: It’s a `d3.selection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
The solution below did indeed satisfy the compiler, but only superficially. I discovered that from then on, typescript assumed I was passing a string and complained a lot.

The final fix (as yet) was to use the optional `key ValueFn`. The declaration files are not terribly helpful, but essentially, I was able to change the `.data()` invocation to:

```js
.data(data, () => xKey as string)
```

This only works because I’m using generics and passing the key as props to the react component, but maybe this will help someone along their journey.

**Outdated solution below**

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040750/how-to-make-data-key-function-to-work-with-typescript/61045443#61045443). All it needed was to return a string, à la:

```
data(d => String(d[dataKey]))
```