# How to make D3 .data() parameter recognize typescript type of input data?

Tags: typescript, d3.js

How do I make d3 data() function understand the type of my data?

D3 data() thinks the parameter `d` is of type `unknown`, which is not true.

```js
interface DataType {
  id: string;
  display: string;
}

const mydata: DataType[] = [{ id: "abc", display: "First Value" }];

d3.selectAll("rect").data(mydata, (d) => d.id); 
//(parameter) d: unknown
```

Hovering over the `(d)` in VSCode I get the typescript message `(parameter) d: unknown`

Hovering over the  `=> d.id` in VSCode I see the the typescript error `Object is of type unknown ts(2571)`

In another closely related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61040750/how-to-make-data-key-function-to-work-with-typescript), some suggested making sure the result d.id is forced as a string, but this still does not work for me. However, it does change the typescript error.

```js
//force string
d3.selectAll("rect").data(mydata, (d: DataType) => `${d.id}`);
```

Argument of type '(d: DataType) => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ValueFn<BaseType | HTMLElement, unknown, KeyType>'.
Types of parameters 'd' and 'datum' are incompatible.
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'DataType'.ts(2345)

I'm using typescript 4.8.2
I installed the whole of d3 with `npm istall d3` and the version is 7.6.1

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example and I will try to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can annotate the type for the selection, which makes it possible for Typescript to show the correct type.

```
interface DataType {
  id: string;
  display: string;
}

const mydata: DataType[] = [{ id: "abc", display: "First Value" }];

d3.selectAll<SVGRectElement, DataType>("rect")
  .data<DataType>(mydata, (d) => d.id);
```

The related source code is here: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/2b229cce80b334f673f1b26895007e9eca786366/types/d3-selection/index.d.ts#L720

Comment: I was selecting svg `g` elements, so I used `d3.selectAll<SVGElement, DataType>`. Thank you for your answer, my typescript errors are gone.

Comment: Great, that it works. :) `SVGElement` is an `SVG` element. `SVGGElement` (extra `G`) is a `G` element.